# Ionic 6 with React - environment variable

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, environment-variables

So I started to learn Ionic and got an issue with environment variables.

I created an env.local file inside the root folder, added `REACT_APP_API:'...'`.
I did stop and restart the server but my `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API)` log `undefined` and not the text inside of it.

Am I using it wrong with Ionic?

Solution:

I changed it to REACT_APP_API=myurl and it solved my issue as @MarcoKlein said.

Comment: Which Ionic version are you using? Looks like you might have to change your `.env` assigment to look like this: `REACT_APP_API=myurl`